# Why does sentence.strip() remove certain characters but not others from the end of this string?

Tags: python

Tyring to figure out how strip() works when reading characters in a string.

This:

```
sentence = "All the single ladies"
sentence = sentence.strip("All the si")
print(sentence)
```

returns this:

```
ngle lad
```

I get why 'All the si' is removed from the start of the string. But how does Python decide to remove the 'ies' from the end of the string? If the 'e' is being removed from the 'ies', why isn't it being removed from 'the' too? What are the rules for string stripping behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.strip()` accepts an iterable of characters you want to remove not a substring. So all of `i`, `e`, `s` characters are present in the substring you passed (All th***e si***). And `d` (that is at the end of the resulting string) isn't, so it stops on it.

See more in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip).

To remove the substring you would use:

```
sentence.replace("All the si", "")
```

Comment: OK so it basically starts eating from both ends and stops as soon as it reaches something that's not on the menu. Got it thanks.